# test: too many arguments returns

Tags: linux, command-line, scripting

I saw other posts the same problem, but I can't figure out since everyone does different things. I'm new to shell script as well, so my limited knowledge is getting more confused when I read those posts.

I have this scrip work perfectly well on another server, but somehow on the new server, I need to check different service names and the script returns error above. I hope you can help me point out what I'm doing wrong here.

The error is: `line 9: test: too many arguments`

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

GREEN=0
YELLOW=1
RED=2

pid=`/bin/ps -eo fname,pid | /usr/bin/awk '{if ($1 == "sshd") print $2}'`

if test $pid
then
        message="sshd Server is running. PID: $pid"
        status=$GREEN
else
        message="sshd Server is stopped."
        status=$RED
fi
echo $message
exit $status
```

Comment: Echo the content of `pid` to console before you use it. What does it contain? And what exactly do you want to test it against? Edit your question and add the necessary details. But first take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how you can improve your question in general.

Comment: Add an `echo  $pid`at line 8, It seems you have more than one PID inside your variable

Comment: You probably want to use `pgrep` rather than a far too complicated pipeline with `ps`. Or, you may want to use a dedicated service command to check whether `sshd` is running or not (like `rcctl check sshd` on OpenBSD systems, possibly something involving `systemd` or `systemctl` or some such thing on Linux).

Comment: Calling anything `test` is a bad idea, as that is the name of a shell builtin/standard command, and that definition might be used instead of yours...

Comment: @vonbrand What is called `test` the only use of test is the shell built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have lot of ssh connections...

Try this,

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

GREEN=0
YELLOW=1
RED=2

pid=(`/bin/ps -eo fname,pid | /usr/bin/awk '{ if ($4 == "abc") print $2}'`)

if  [ ${#pid[@]} -gt 0 ]
then
        message="sshd Server is running. PID: ${pid[@]}"
        status=$GREEN
else
        message="sshd Server is stopped."
        status=$RED
fi
echo $message
exit $status
```

if you just want only the PID of ssh service, try the below

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

GREEN=0
YELLOW=1
RED=2

pid=`cat /var/run/sshd.pid`
if test $pid
then
        message="sshd Server is running. PID: $pid"
        status=$GREEN
else
        message="sshd Server is stopped."
        status=$RED
fi
echo $message
exit $status
```

Comment: Thank you so much Murphy and  Kusalananda, the second modification much simpler and works like a charm. The PID of SSH script is much more efficient. Thank you for pointing out the problem so fast. Thank you, everyone, for your recommendation, I very appreciate your time and advised.

Best Regards,
PN

Comment: @GAD3R Agreed !!! there are lot more to be improved.... like unnecessary variables... just want to help OP only to solve his error...

Answer (score -1):

Use the quotes:

I.e.

`if test "$pid"`